# JRip.RipperRule.toString(classAttr) gives wrong consequent

Tags: java, weka

I'm using jRip to classify unlabeled instances. Besides the class, I want to know which rule was triggered.
With the method covers() I know if the instance is covered by the rule, which seems to work. But when I want to print the rule human readable using the toString(classAttr) method it shows the wrong consequent. My code

```
FastVector ruleset = rip.getRuleset();
for (int j = 0; j < ruleset.size(); j++) {
    JRip.RipperRule rule = (JRip.RipperRule) ruleset.elementAt(j);

     System.out.println("consequent of the rule: " + rule.getConsequent());
     System.out.println("rule:" + rule.toString(unlabeled.classAttribute()) + " /// covers = " + rule.covers(unlabeled.instance(i)));
}
```

When I iterate through the ruleset using the code above I get:

```
====================================================================
consequent of the rule: 0.0
rule:(humidity = high) and (outlook = sunny) => play=yes /// covers = false
====================================================================
consequent of the rule: 0.0
rule:(outlook = rainy) and (windy = TRUE) => play=yes /// covers = false
====================================================================
consequent of the rule: 1.0
rule: => play=no /// covers = true
```

When using:

```
System.out.println(rip.toString());
```

I get (which is correct):

```
(humidity = high) and (outlook = sunny) => play=no (3.0/0.0)
(outlook = rainy) and (windy = TRUE) => play=no (2.0/0.0)
=> play=yes (9.0/0.0)
```

The problem is that in the first log it says play=>yes when it's actually play=>no.

I'm using the weather.nominal.arff dataset (comes with Weka).

Answer (score 0):

While JRip builds the classifier (See the method buildClassifier), it reorders the class Attribute in the ascending order "most frequent". As far as I can tell, you don't reorder the class Attribute you provide to the rule.toString().

In order to keep them the same, you have to reorder the class Attribute before handing it to the rule.toString()